# SELECT RECORDS INTO ARRAY

Tags: php

I'm neubie with PHP. I need to build some Web Service so, I have problems.. please help me.

I have this code, I have to put in array the Select's records and the return in JSON.

The CODE...

```
 function redeem() {
 // Check for required parameters
if (isset($_POST["id_cliente"]) && isset($_POST["id_sucursal"])) {
    // Put parameters into local variables
    $cliente = $_POST["id_cliente"];
    $sucursal = $_POST["id_sucursal"];
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id_arbitro FROM arbitro WHERE id_cliente =? AND id_sucursal =?') or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $cliente, $sucursal);
    $stmt->execute();
    //$stmt->bind_result($id_arbitro);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $cuantos = count($result);
    echo "$cuantos";

    $registros = 0;
    /*while ($stmt->fetch()) {                      
        $registros ++;
        // Return unlock code, encoded with JSON
        $result = array("id_arbitro" => $stmt,);
        echo "$id_arbitro !";
    }
    */
    $stmt->close();
    if ($registros < 0) {
        sendResponse(400,"No existen arbitros con los parámetros recibidos");
        return false;
    } 

    //echo json_encode($result);
    sendResponse(200, "FIN");
    //printf("ERROR %s",$registros);
    return true;
}
sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');
return false;
```

}

Comment: So which part are you having trouble with? We can't see the syntax of the class `$this->db` points to, but you essentially need to iterate the results, put them into an array, and json_encode(); it

Comment: Hi Helion. SELECT instruccion it's fine works .. If I uncomment the WHILE instuction, I can get value in $registros variable, but I can't put the records in the array ... $result = array("id_arbitro" => $stmt,);, when I tried to get de count array's items I only have gotten one record count($result), that it's my trouble

Comment: I've answered based on this information.

Answer (score 0):

To encode the results of your query, use something like that

```
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
```

Comment: how can I check that $results has all my records, with count($results) ? ... becouse last doesen't work

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do sizeof($results) or count($result).
If you wan to return the count in your json, just do:

return json_encode(array('Result'=>$results, 'count' => sizeof($results));

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you're having trouble understanding how to put them all into an array.

First, make sure that whatever you use for database calls doesn't already have a `fetchAll` style function that could do this for you.

If you still need to do, you need to define an array first and then add to it:

```
$results = array();
while ($record = $stmt->fetch()) {                      
    $registros ++;
    $results[] = $record;
}
print json_encode($results);
```

The syntax might vary slightly for your database class but this gives you an idea.

Comment: I've provided an example of a loop but you need to look at the documentation for the database access classes you're using.

Comment: I work with Mysql ..  $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'futchoco', 'Futcho19', 'futchoco_futsoft');